# Moodle iframe route

Tags: routes, moodle

I'm trying to have 2 moodle on the same server, but I have trouble routes that are created when a file is uploaded, I understand folder called "iframe" sia omeone know me know where I can change this path? to have 2, iframe iframe site 1 and site 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have the same data directory for both Moodles. You will need to have a separate data directory for each Moodle installation.

eg:

in `config.php` for Moodle 1

```
$CFG->dataroot = '/var/www/sitedata1';
```

in `config.php` for Moodle 2

```
$CFG->dataroot = '/var/www/sitedata2';
```